# How to use popover view as Collapsible view on click of tableview cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I want that on a click of a tableview cell a popover view appears and rest all the cells should shift beneath popover.Just as the case for collapsible view.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want the rest of the cells to move then the view you are showing would not be a popover view.  It would be better to implement something like an expanding/collapsing list view.  Using this paradigm your 'cells' would be section headers and clicking on them would expand (with animation) to display the cell or cells within containing the content you wanted in the popover view. *I've done something similar recently but can't find useful example code right now*

Comment: Have a look at [this.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010139)

Answer (score 0):

[This sample project contains popover view in table view cell.](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover)

Add `[self.yourView removefromsuperView ];`